# ui5 webcomponents: Custom style webcomponent doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, ui5-webcomponents

Custom style for [webcomponent `ui5-tabcontainer`](https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground/?path=/docs/main-tab-container--docs) doesnt work.

The doc says:

> ...  allow developers to **style elements inside the Shadow DOM**. The
> ui5-tabcontainer exposes the following CSS Shadow Parts:
> content - **Used to style** the content of the component

This is what i've done (vue application):

```
// template.tpl
<nav id="dummyIdent">
    <ui5-tabcontainer 
        fixed
        collapsed
        data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true" 
        header-background-design="Transparent"
        tab-layout="Inline"
        @tab-select="navClicked">
        <ui5-tab      
            tooltip="Text"
            icon="notes"
            text="text">
        </ui5-tab>
    </ui5-tabcontainer>
</nav>

// style.scss
#dummyIdent {
    background: #eff4f9;
    ui5-tabcontainer::part(content) {
        opacity: 0;
        color: brown;
        .ui5-tab-strip-item-icon-outer {
            background: red;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect changes of the default style, but nothings happens.
The goal is to **change the background of the icon** provided by the `ui5-tab` inside the `ui5-tabcontainer`

**Why the css config doesn't work? What do i wrong?**

Comment: (I don't know UI5) ``::part`` can only style the DOM at the level ``part="content`` was defined (by the UI5 developers) it can not style elements down the tree, that would defeat the whole purpose of DOM parts.

Comment: UI5 needs to add another ``part`` OR ``exportparts`` for this to work: _The global attribute ``part`` **makes the element visible on just a single level of depth**. When the shadow tree is nested, parts will be visible only to the parent of the shadow tree but not to its ancestor. Exporting parts further down is exactly what ``exportparts`` attribute is for._ [MDN exportparts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/exportparts)